# Use different archive template for plugin

Tags: plugin-development, templates, archive-template

In my blog, I'm using a plugin for an encyclopedia. Unfortunately, the plugin uses the archive template from my blog.

How can I use a different page / template for the encyclopedia? Here is the function of the plugin: (From the plugin-author I didn't get any support).

```
function Define_Rewrite_Rules(){
$post_type = Get_Post_Type_Object($this->post_type);
$archive_url_path = $post_type->rewrite['slug'];
$this->rewrite_rules[SPrintF('%s/filter:([^/]+)/?$', $archive_url_path)] = SPrintF('index.php?post_type=%s&filter=$matches[1]', $this->post_type);
$this->rewrite_rules[SPrintF('%s/filter:([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$', $archive_url_path)] = SPrintF('index.php?post_type=%s&filter=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', $this->post_type);
}
```

Comment: Have you read the [Template Hierarchy page in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display)?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new template in your theme named `archive-encyclopedia.php`.

In your theme folder, copy the `archive.php` or `index.php` and name it `archive-encyclopedia.php`. Now you can make your custom changes to the new template.

This template will be called instead of the default archive template as `archive-{post-type}.php` will be used before `archive.php` or `index.php`.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. This way only those who know can know what you're suggesting. Read [answer] for some guidance.